# Restricted accumulation of values

Tags: programming, list-manipulation

Please consider the following list `data`. I was trying to accumulate `data` until the result turns positive the first time and finally found an approach. Maybe it's useful to others and maybe there are other (more efficient) approaches:

```
data={-1050, 50, 1001, 1950, 1950, 1950, 525, 0};
```

The same what `Accumulate` does can be done by `FoldList`:

```
Rest@FoldList[Plus, 0, data] == Rest@FoldList[#1 + #2 &, 0, data] == Accumulate@data
(*True*)
```

Now, one can add constraints to `FoldList`. For my problem I had to write:

```
Rest[FoldList[If[#1 + #2 < #2, #1 + #2, #2] &, 0, #]]&@data
(*{-1050, -1000, 1, 1950, 1950, 1950, 525, 0}*)
```

**Question**

How can this be improved, either in terms of speed or elegance?

Comment: I'd suggest you add "How can this be improved, either in terms of speed or elegance" or something like that at the end. Then it's a question!

Comment: @acl I added your advice.

Comment: At the very least, you should have started with simplifying the two-argument function: `If[#1 < 0, #1, 0] + #2 &`. The versions using `Boole[]` or `UnitStep[]` seemed a bit slower in my tests; someone might want to do more testing on those.

Comment: Do you want your output to stop at the point the accumulation goes positive? The answers provide some examples that do this and some that don't. Might be useful to clarify. You could use something like `LengthWhile` or `TakeWhile` to obtain that output from the full list.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch The code-line with `FoldList` is only there to describe how I got to the last code-line. The most crucial point to me was to formulate an alternative to `Accumulate` with the addition of implementing `conditions`.

Comment: @J.M. I'm not really a fan of `If` (I got the prejudice that it slows down calculations) but I wonder whether in this case really another approach would be faster.

Comment: @J.M. What about the `If`-clause? Do have an idea how one could substitute this part of my code with another expression?

Comment: John, there's `Boole[]` for instance, since `Boole[cond]` is equivalent to `If[cond, 1, 0]`...

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way:

```
With[{acc = Accumulate@data}, acc[[;; -#]] ~Join~ data[[-# + 1 ;;]] &@Count[acc, _?Positive]]
(* {-1050, -1000, 1, 1950, 1950, 1950, 525, 0} *)
```

You can also use `Tr@Boole@Thread[acc > 0]]` instead of `Count[...]` or if you want `≥0`, then you can use `Tr@UnitStep[acc]`.

Comment: `HeavisideTheta[0]` is undefined, so this has problems if the total reaches zero.

Comment: @SimonWoods Good point. Fixed now :)

Comment: UnitStep doesn't have that problem

Comment: @Rojo Yep, I mentioned it in my answer, but note that `UnitStep` is equivalent to `≥0`, whereas OP only mentioned `>0`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you had mentioned it. 1-UnitStep[-#] would fix that, but it's less fast. He mentioned wanting >0 but actually programmed >=0

Comment: Also I think this approach would only work for data whose accumulation doesn't go negative after getting positive for the first time, right?

Comment: @Rojo Here's a fix. Not only is it straightforward, it's fast: `Block[{sums = Accumulate[data], k, i}, 
 k = Position[sums, x_?Positive, 1, 1];  
 i = If[k == {}, 0, Part[k, 1, 1]]; Take[sums, i]~Join~Drop[data, i]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps if you like recursion this might seem more elegant, it certainly doesn't win on speed.

**Recursive**

```
NestWhile[{First@#~Plus~#[[2, 1]], Rest@#[[2]]} &, {0, data}, 
 NonPositive@First@# && Length@#[[2]] >= 1 &]
```

> {1, {1950, 1950, 1950, 525, 0}}

**Timing:**

```
data = RandomInteger[{-1000, 10}, 100000];

AbsoluteTiming[
 NestWhile[{First@#~Plus~#[[2, 1]], Rest@#[[2]]} &, {0, data}, 
   NonPositive@First@# && Length@#[[2]] >= 1 &];]
```

> {1.005087, Null}

**rm -rf**

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 With[{acc=Accumulate@data},acc[[;; -#]]~Join~data[[-# + 1 ;;]] &@Count[acc,_?Positive]];]
```

> {0.024329, Null}

**Rojo**

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Join[#, data[[Length@# + 1 ;;]]] &@
   Reap[Fold[If[NonPositive@#1, Sow[#1 + #2], Break[Null, Fold]] &, 0,
       data]][[-1, 1]];]
```

> {0.104658, Null}

Comment: The second method is very fast but is correct only assuming the cumulative sums remain positive forever after they first turn positive.

Comment: @whuber Yes indeed, thank you for noting that :) The second method, I think, came from an earlier version of the answer from rm -rf which has now been updated in light of comments from Simon Woods which I'd missed. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
Join[#, data[[Length@# + 1 ;;]]] &@
 Reap[Fold[If[NonPositive@#1, Sow[#1 + #2], Break[Null, Fold]] &, 0, 
    data]][[-1, 1]]
```

> {-1050, -1000, 1, 1950, 1950, 1950, 525, 0}